# Amazon EC2 cannot connect to PostgreSQL database

Tags: php, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am connecting to my PostgreSQL database via PHP using a Public IP (IPv4) provided in EC2 instance. The PHP is running but it does not let me create a connection with the database.

postgresql.conf:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

pg_hba.conf:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::/0                    trust
```

php file:

```
$host        = "host = IPREMOVED ";
$port        = "port = 5432";
$dbname      = "dbname = dbName";
$credentials = "user = CREDENTIALREMOVED password = CREDENTIALREMOVED";

$response = array();

$db = pg_connect("$host $port $dbname $credentials");
if(!$db){
    echo "Connection Not established\n";
}
else{
    echo "sample code";
    pg_close($db);
}
```

Comment: "does not let you create a connection". Error message/behaviour description?

Comment: "Connection Not established"

Answer (score 1):

First thing : Hope you have given the wrong credentials here, just looks like the real ones. If not, please do change the original db credentials first!

Before going with php have you verified the port connection using telnet or shell?

Please do the following and see if it connects. Otherwise it will just be 
security group rule in AWS.

```
telnet 13.126.184.172 5432
```

And it connects(will show the escape character thing), do also the db connection using psql commands.

Comment: It states  "could not open connection to the host, on port 5432", but I have added HTTP, PostgreSQL, SSH as inbound rule in my security group

Comment: Did you do proper configuration with postgres to map it to external IP. I see your configurations in the question, but just make sure you did it wrong.
Also did you run psql connection commands in shell from the instance where php rests?

Comment: http://customer.docushare.xerox.com/s.nl/ctype.KB/it.I/id.29778/KB.1777/.f

See if this helps.